# Excel VBA: Copy one column's figures to another + if condition

Tags: excel, vba

My case is like this: Copy column B's number (if column A's adjacent cell is n/a) to Column A of sheet 2 from A1 to A2 to A3, etc (one by one)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI9Fh.jpg)

This code works:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
If Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/A" Then Worksheets(2).Range("A" & 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = 
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i
```

BTW: can anyone guide me through this: Worksheets(2).Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) 
I copy it from stackflow but I don't understand it clearly

However, I don't understand why this one doesn't work:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

LastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
j = Worksheets(2).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
If Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/A" Then Worksheets(2).Range("A" & j + 1) = 
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value


Next i
End Sub
```

This output is:

**Column A of sheet 2

4**

(It doesn't have the loop one by one but the previous figure is replaced by the later one) I think I use j to replace the long sentence of the first case but it doesn't work

Comment: `If Cells(i, 1).Text = "#N/A" Then Worksheets(2).Range("A" & j + 1) = 
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).TEXT` If you have to compare #N/A to the cell's text property, what makes you think you can write #N/A as a value?

Comment: To understand the LastRow code, or any future code, you found on Stack (although the one you posted looks funky) , you can put it in a sheet and step through (F8) line by line, then you can hover over each variable and see the value that it is storing to help you follow the logic. Essentially it is counting down to last available row, using the CTRL+SHIFT+UP feature, and returning the row where you end up at (hence the .Row at end).